# VBA Date Range Not Filtering

Tags: excel, vba

There are many QA on this topic but nothing seems to answer this simple question.  I'm not sure why this is code is not working - All I need to do is filter column Q with a date range.  What happens is this removes (filters) all items; it does not leave the date range selected:

```
Dim StDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

StDate = "1/20/21"
EndDate = "2/2/21"

With ActiveSheet

.Range("Q1:Q2500").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & StDate, xlAnd, "<=" & EndDate

End With
```

Comment: Try enclosing `StDate` and `EndDate` in `DateValue`.

Comment: StDate = DateValue("1/20/21")

EndDate = DateValue("2/2/21")

same result

Comment: Does column Q contain actual dates (formatted numbers), or text-that-looks-like-dates?

Comment: Short Date - formatted 1/1/21

Comment: If you change the format to General, do you see a number like `44197`?

Comment: yes 10/1/21 becomes 4470.xxxxx

Comment: Then try `.Range("Q1:Q2500").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & CLng(StDate), xlAnd, "<=" & Clng(EndDate)`.

Comment: This didnt work either :(  .Range("Q1:Q2500").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & CLng(StDate), xlAnd, "<=" & Clng(EndDate)

Comment: That's odd because `.Range("Q1:Q2500").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & CLng(StDate), xlAnd, "<=" & CLng(EndDate)` works for me. What does the filter show after the macro is run ?

Comment: it hides them all as if none meet the criteria.  out of 2200 there are 43.  I ran the manual filter between range on the sheet which works fine.  thanks for trying!

Comment: The criteria need to be strings e.g.: Dim sDate As String: sDate = "1/20/21", or use sDate = ">=1/20/21" in the first place.

Comment: Tried strings - same result 
Dim StDate As String
Dim EndDate As String
StDate = "1/20/21"
EndDate = "2/2/21"

With ActiveSheet

.Range("Q1:Q2500").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & StDate, xlAnd, "<=" & EndDate
End With

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filter Between Dates

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilterBetweenDates()
    
    Const Crit1 As String = ">=1/20/21"
    Const Crit2 As String = "<=2/2/21"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ' remove possbile previous filter
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("Q1:Q2500")
    
    rg.AutoFilter 1, Crit1, xlAnd, Crit2
    
End Sub
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! ty!